# How to add click event to each quarter of circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, click

The goal is to add a function to each quarter of a circle.

The circle was generated the following way:
HTML:

```
<div class="circle">
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
    margin: 1em auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red green blue yellow;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

like i found here: [How to create circle with four quarters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955574/how-to-create-circle-with-four-quarters)

I want to execute the function quarterClicked() when a specific quarter was clicked.

Comment: I don’t think that is it possible to have four different event listener, since it’s just a single element in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can draw your circle like :

```
<div class="circle">
  <div id="blue" class="quarter" onclick="quarterClicked()"></div>
  <div id="green" class="quarter" onclick="q2()"></div>
  <div id="red" class="quarter" onclick="q3()"></div>
  <div id="black" class="quarter" onclick="q4()"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.circle {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.quarter {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}

#black {
  background-color: black;
}
```

javaScript:

```
quarterClicked(){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Do you also know a way of how to make a quarter bigger on hover?

Comment: yes , add :hover in quarter class and change width ,height